# How to make active record queries when attributes uses enumerize

Tags: ruby-on-rails, enumerize

```
class AppointmentResponse < ActiveRecord::Base
...
  extend Enumerize
  enumerize :status, in: %i[unreviewed approved rejected], default: :unreviewed
...
end
```

Migration:

```
def change
   add_column :appointment_responses, :status, :string
end
```

So with this, my thinking is that I should be able to make queries like:

```
AppointmentResponse.where(status: :unreviewed)
```

But this returns: []

But I know that to be false. Exibit A:

```
 #<AppointmentResponse:0x007feb02c5d290
  id: 16,
  ...
  status: "unreviewed">
```

And I can confirm that I haven't made some terrible character error by:

```
AppointmentResponse.last.status == "unreviewed"

true
```

What am I missing? I've also switched `extend Enumerize` to `include Enumerize`. It's still the same. I've also tried adding 
`scope: true` and `predicates: true`, still no. I know Enumerize works with active record. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out I needed to added to the migration:

def change
   add_column :appointment_responses, :status, :string, default: 'unreviewed'
end